Two Disagreeing Approaches to Applying Parallel Axis Theorem to a Rod
I've been staring at this simple rotational inertia problem for a while, but I keep getting two different answers.
We have a uniform, thin rod with mass M and length L. Its pivot point is a distance L/3 from the top of the rod. What is the rotational inertia of the rod?
Approach 1: we know that the rotational inertia of a rod about a point at its end is M(L^2)/3.
Since the pivot point is L/3 from the end of the rod, we can use the parallel axis theorem:
I = Icm - Mh^2 = M(L^2)/3 - M(L/3)^2 = 2M(L^2)/9
Approach 2: we know that the rotational inertia of a rod about a point at its center is M(L^2)/12.
Since the pivot point is L/6 from the center of the rod, we can use the parallel axis theorem:
I = Icm - Mh^2 = M(L^2)/12 + M(L/6)^2 = 4M(L^2)/36 = M(L^2)/9.
Clearly, one of these approaches is wrong... But I am struggling to find a mistake with either approach.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

As with all theorems, you have to read the entire statement of the theorem to know when and how to apply it, and you have to copy and apply the formulas accurately. There is already an answer below that explains how this theorem should be applied to this problem.

The parallel axis theorem only applies when you start from an axis of rotation through the center of mass. This is what the "cm" in the formula $I = I_{\mathrm{cm}} + Md^2$ means: it stands for "center (of)  mass".
(A consequence of the parallel axis theorem is that $I \ge I_{\mathrm{cm}}$, because the squared term is nonnegative: the moment of inertia always increases when you move the axis away from the center of mass. If starting at the center of mass weren't a hypothesis of the theorem, then we'd be saying "all moments of inertia are bigger than all others" which is nonsense.)

Thank you! It looks like I was taught wrong in high school... we used the incorrect approach to correctly find I=1/12 MR^2 for a rod whose pivot is at its center.

I mean, the formula $I = I_{\mathrm{cm}} + Md^2$ works in both directions. If you know $I_{\mathrm{cm}}$ and $Md^2$, you can use it to find $I$. But if you know $I$ and $Md^2$, you can use it to solve for $I_{\mathrm{cm}}$.

You could even imagine a scenario where you use it to solve for $d$. If you have an object that has a moment of inertia of $50,\mathrm{kg}\cdot \mathrm{m}^2$ about an axis through its center of mass, and $100,\mathrm{kg}\cdot \mathrm{m}^2$ about a parallel axis through point $P$, and weighs $2,\mathrm{kg}$, you can write $100=50+2d^2$ and get $d=5$, concluding that $P$ is $5,\mathrm{m}$ away from the center of mass.

That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!
